# Error when I use an aggregate function count in my report using JPQL language

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Somthing happened to my account (I can't access to it !!!!),so I will ask again my question :(
I can't use an aggregate function in my JPQL request in my report:
**this is my report.jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports  http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Test" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
<property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
<property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
<parameter name="priority" class="java.lang.String">
<defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>

<queryString language="ejbql">
    **<![CDATA[select count(j) as nb from Jiraissue j where j.priority='3']]>**
</queryString>
    <field name="nb" class="java.lang.Long"/>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">

    </band>
</title>
<pageHeader>
    <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageHeader>
<columnHeader>
    <band height="84" splitType="Stretch">
        <staticText>
            <reportElement x="28" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <text><![CDATA[nb]]></text>
        </staticText>

    </band>
</columnHeader>
<detail>
    <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="50" y="11" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Long">    <![CDATA[$F{nb}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
    <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
</columnFooter>
<pageFooter>
    <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
</pageFooter>
<summary>
    <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
</summary>
</jasperReport>
```

My code java:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =     Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JiraMapPU");
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
Map parameterMap = new HashMap();


parameterMap.put(JRJpaQueryExecuterFactory.PARAMETER_JPA_ENTITY_MANAGER, entityManager);
//parameterMap.put("priority","3");
try
{

JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:/Documents and Settings/a497165/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/JiraMap/src/java/Reports/Test.jrxml");
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,parameterMap);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print,"C:/Documents and Settings/a497165/My  Documents/NetBeansProjects/JiraMap/src/java/Reports/Test.pdf");
}
catch (JRException ex)

{
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

**The error:**

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : nb
at    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDat    aSource.java:123)
at   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRJpaDataSource$PropertyReader.getValue(JRJpaDataSource.java:206)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRJpaDataSource.getFieldValue(JRJpaDataSource.java:131)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:821)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:785)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1482)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:126)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:118)
at  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:435)
at Reporting.ReportBean.main(ReportBean.java:41)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'nb' on class 'class  java.lang.Long'
```

Any help please :((

Answer (score 0):

The count function can only be used on a field of an entity, not the entity itself. You could pick any field to count, but it should probably be the primary key as that will never be null. The following query should work though.

```
<![CDATA[select count(j.priority) as nb from Jiraissue j where j.priority='3']]>
```